# Includegraphics without stretching

Tags: beamer, columns, presentations, includegraphics

I am trying to use `\columns` in conjunction with `\includegraphics` to show a "list" of pictures.

Sadly this code:

```
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Einführung}
    \begin{columns}
    \column{0.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=5cm,height=3.5cm]{FiguresAndPictures/AlleAktien-Netflix-Logo.png}\\
        \includegraphics[width=5cm,height=4cm]{FiguresAndPictures/Amazon-Logo.jpg}
    \column{0.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=5cm,height=3.5cm]{FiguresAndPictures/facebook.png}\\
        \includegraphics[width=5cm,height=4cm]{FiguresAndPictures/nn.png}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}
```

Only creates this slide:

[image: fail]

What i would like, is that all images are scaled proportionally to each other, but not be strechted like that ... how do i do that?

Comment: Specify the width or height, but not both.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `graphicx` package provides the `keepaspectratio` key. If you set this, the used keys `width` and `height` are meant as limits, the image is scaled to not exceed either of the two while keeping the same aspect ratio, so instead of using `\usegraphics[width=5cm, height=3.5cm]{<file>}` use `\usegraphics[width=5cm, height=3.5cm, keepaspectratio]{<file>}`.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{duckuments} % for random duck pics
\usepackage[]{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\includegraphics{example-image-duck}

%distorted
\includegraphics[width=7cm, height=3.5cm]{example-image-duck}

%using either of the two
\includegraphics[width=7cm]{example-image-duck}

%using either of the two
\includegraphics[height=3.5cm]{example-image-duck}

% using both and keepaspectratio, results in the smaller of the two above
\includegraphics[width=7cm, height=3.5cm, keepaspectratio]{example-image-duck}
\end{document}
```